# How to read text file and pipe to HTML table using Node.js and Express

Tags: html, node.js, express, html-table

I am running Node.js with Express and am fairly new to the world of Javascript. I am trying to find a way of parsing a text file and outputting certain data from that file into a HTML table. I am able to open and read the file using `fs.read` and then output it to the console but I'm unsure of how to go about passing specific data from that string into table entries.

I'm not looking for someone else to write the code for me just some general advice and pointers would be really helpful to get me on my way.

Comment: Stackoverflow expects specific problems in questions. Asking for general advice doesn't fit the guidelines in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Please post the code you have, make an attempt at doing what you want, then explain specifically where you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

Without additional code, I can't be any more specific than this. There may be other reasons you wouldn't want to do it this way. So I would first recommend being more specific in your questions.

I would say reading in the file and creating a string of the desired HTML table at server start time. So in your `server.js` file (or `app.js` or whatever file you run with node) you'd have something like this to [read the file](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var htmlTable = '';
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  var parsedData = parseData(data);
  htmlTable = createTable(parsedData);
});

app.get('/htmlTable', function(req, res){
  res.send(htmlTable);
});

app.listen(3000);
```